# PHP Login form validation failed

Tags: php

I have following login form pointing to the file '../exe/form-exec.php'.

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="../exe/login-exec.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="112"><b>Login</b></td>
      <td width="188"><input name="login" type="text" class="textfield" id="login" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Password</b></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" id="password" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Where login-exec.php should validate where inputs login & password has been field and if NOT return to the form file with `$errflag`.

File login-exec.php:

```
//Start session
    session_start();

    //Include database connection details
    require_once('../inc/config.php');

    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;



..... 



//Input Validations
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: ../form/login-form.php");
            exit();
}
```

**And partly is working correctly - it is returning to the form - but no error is displayed.
Any suggestion much appreciated.**

Comment: Where are your PHP code that displays the error messages?

Comment: There isn't any. Sorry. I doing some exercises with PHP - it's new to me. PHP checking the array of `$errmsg_arr` should be places in login-form.php, should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same page as your html form, do something similar to this:

```
session_start();
foreach ($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) {
  echo $msg . "<br />";
}
etc...
```

To actually display the messages.

Comment: This is working. But, straight away on login page there is an error displayed - even without entering any data. Just a guess that array is saved from previous login failure. How to change that?

Comment: If session is dead: 

`Notice: Undefined index: ERRMSG_ARR in C:\wamp\www\form\login-form.php on line 3`
and `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\form\login-form.php on line 3`

**If session is live but loggout - error msg straight away.**

If ignore the error when the session is dead and press 'submit' correct error msg is displayed without errors.

Comment: Try to surround the code with this: if(isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'])) {
// Code here
}

Comment: Yep. This is working now. Now need to handle incorrect data entry :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are valorizing the `$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']` but then when you return to the form you're not checking/using it... try to add this to the form code

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!is_null($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'])) {
    echo '<div class="errmsg">Error...</div>';
}
?>
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="../exe/login-exec.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
...
```

Anyway this type of validation handling (using session parameters) is **heavily discouraged**...

Try to follow some [design patterns](http://www.phppatterns.com/docs/design/strategy_pattern) instead ;)

Comment: This will return `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\form\login-form.php on line 2`. Sorry, I'm new to PHP - first login system of my

Comment: I would suggest to use any PHP framework in the first place ;) or use an ajax validation. Anyway, if this is for "practice" purpose, you can simply put the validation & the form code in the same file and make the form put to itself. So you will have to check the $_POST parameters and if they are correct forward the page to the desired page (or directly show the error)

Answer (score 0):

When getting data submitted from a form with `POST` method, it is better to use `$_POST['login']` instead of `$login` since if `register_globals` is `off` it won't work. 
This might be your problem.

Comment: Yep. register_globals = off, I will try to change it.

Comment: @Pete: No, let register_globals off. This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.